# issue while synchronising PHP (reading file) and Ajax (jquery ui slider)

Tags: php, ajax

I got an issue while trying to display a jquery UI slider with its range based on a values read with PHP from a text file.
Its seems that it's a syncrhonising issue as I get the error: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable" code: 11"

Is there a way I can force the jquery UI slider to wait for the value to be present or to work in synchrone mode ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where does the error comes from? Is it a javscript or php error? I guess it's javascript but you didn't really precise...

In your php script, you should read your text file first, build a string that contains the html/javascript code of the ui slider declaration with the right values, and once this is done output the string.

Thus when you browser reads the source, it will initialize your slider with the correct values.

Comment: I did what you said, but still the javascript that is called from the string built on my php page returns the error. The line in error is myVideo.currentTime = s_start; where s_start is the value i'm reading from the text file. 
Do you have any idea why this is occurring?